# TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type decimal.Decimal which has no callable arccos method

Tags: pandas, pyspark, python-3.7

I'm trying to convert the Pyspark data frame into a pandas data frame.

meanwhile calculating long, lat values and updating them into a data frame.

```
def cos_max_longitude(radian_longitude, radian_latitude):
    return radian_longitude + np.arcsin(np.sin(r) / np.arccos(radian_latitude))
```

Error Stack :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/src/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/src/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/src/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 345, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/usr/local/src/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 141, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/usr/local/src/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 334, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/src/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/usr/local/src/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/test.py", line 1847, in cos_max_longitude
    np.arcsin(np.sin(r) / np.arccos(radian_latitude))
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type decimal.Decimal which has no callable arccos method
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically error is in np.arccos(radian_latitude)

*My suggestion would be to check data type of radian_latitude also check data type of the value stored inside it*

*If its 'decimal.Decimal' then convert it to simple float datatype.*

Refer below links :

https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#optional-keyword-arguments
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arccos.html

Comment: Thank you @AjikyaBhore, radian_latitude is decimal.